# JBAS015852: Could not index class module-info.class - WARNING at startup

Tags: java, jackson, gson, wildfly

We use some jars are libraries in our app.

The app runs inside WildFly.

I am getting now these warnings when starting up WildFly
after upgrading certain jars/libraries.

WildFly version is 8

JDK/JRE version is also 8   ( 1.8.0_192 in particular )

Not sure what this warning means. Seems related to this
https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238
but I don't fully understand it.

I have some guesses (based on the info that I found on the web)
that these JARs are "too new" and follow some new JDK 9 JAR model,
and so are not compatible maybe with JDK 8. But I am not quite sure.

So I am looking for a more authoritative explanation.

- How can this warning be fixed/cleared?
- Also, in general is there a way to find what was the latest version
  of a given library/JAR which was JDK 8 based (and not JDK 9 based)?

  ```
    2021-02-22 13:32:19,986 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015852: Could not index class module-info.class at /C:/wr/server/wildfly/standalone/deployments/report.war/WEB-INF/lib/gson-2.8.6.jar: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=4 poolCount = 20
        at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.processConstantPool(Indexer.java:619) [jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:653) [jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:100) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_192]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_192]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_192]

    2021-02-22 13:32:20,730 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015852: Could not index class module-info.class at /C:/wr/server/wildfly/standalone/deployments/report.war/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.11.3.jar: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=3 poolCount = 34
        at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.processConstantPool(Indexer.java:619) [jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:653) [jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:100) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_192]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_192]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_192]
  ```

Comment: Gson introduced Java 9 module declaration back in [2017](https://github.com/google/gson/commit/7ddac52748c59228cb86d08d60b417ce737a0563) then released in 2018 (2.8.3 I guess). Not sure how they build the lib though. Try to downgrade to 2.8.2 if it works.